# armeabi-v7a in Android split apk

Tags: android, apk

I have an android application if I use splitting for publishing my app and I upload only armeabi-v7a apk. What are the problems I am likely to face. Is it a bad practice ? I have already used pro guard to reduce my app size and have minimized all my images .

Answer (score 0):

Not bad practice, but it can be harmful if it's not use for specific needs (like using native libraries and such). You should check the https://developer.android.com/google/play/publishing/multiple-apks.html for clarifications. One immediate drawback is apk management (versions, updates and alike). 
Before doing that, as I said, try asking around/ read advices from others.

Comment: I want to reduce my app size  can you help me ?

Comment: Well, it can be quite a challenge depending on your app's needs. Try reading the guidelines first https://developer.android.com/topic/performance/reduce-apk-size.html. If you can no longer compress your resources, maybe you can rethink your application arhitecture.

Comment: Will I  be able to send updates to my app if i publish armeabi-v7a ?

Comment: Of course it will be possible. But only devices with armeabi-v7a CPU arhitecture will be able to install that apk.